# "The problem is that....". Good or bad English?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, expression-choice, writing-style

I wrote a technical article in which I used (probably overused) constructions of the form "The main point is that...", "The problem is that...". As I am a native Italian speaker, these sentences have the natural form that I would use in my language. One of the reviewers suggested that a better way to formulate these sentences in English is "As the main point,...", "As the problem,...". I feel these sentences carry "less power" than my original ones since the main word is not the subject anymore.
Any thoughts? Is the construction I used incorrect, inelegant, or good English?
Thank you

Comment: I definitely like "*The main point is ..*" better than "*As the main point, ..*". The latter adds nothing except extra words, and as you said weakens the assertion.

Comment: Just to make my question clearer, as an example, the choice would be between "The main problem is that such numbers are hard to find" and "As the main problem, such numbers are hard to find".

Comment: I still strongly prefer the original, no-*as* version. I don't see the virtue in or point of adding *as*.

Comment: @DanBron: The *as* only needed to be added because the *is* was subtracted. Marco: The *that* can be subtracted, leaving *The problem is* as a legitimate alternative to *The problem is that...* Your sense of ***power*** is a matter of style that we don't address here at ELU.

Comment: @ScotM But the *the* is still there? It's just that *as* was added in front of it, making *the* the second word, rather than the first. But I agree with you that the *as* tends to diminish or background the *the*, to the point that it's almost unnoticeable, and combined with making a forceful copula into an independent clause (i.e. forcing the use of that odious little comma), I think the "recommended" version sucks the life and thrust out of the sentence. I do not like it, Sam I Am.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with the style consideration: Leading with *As* leaves *the* with diminished emphasis. *Try it! Try it! You will see!* ;-)

Comment: So he is suggesting you change, for example, "The main point is that our prices are the best." to "As the main point, our prices are the best.", which, unless I'm mistaken, equals "Our prices are the best as the main point.". To me that sentence makes no sense at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ Avon, that's precisely what he is recommending, but I am not sure that it equals your second sentence.

Comment: @ScotM: I like the suggestion you made in your first post, to leave the _that_ out, which leads to "The main problem is such numbers are hard to find". I was taught (abroad) that English always wants its pronouns and prepositions spelled out and never just implied, but sometimes that seems to lead to pedantic sentences.
Another possibility could be "The main problem: such numbers are hard to find", although it sounds more like a math definition than standard written English.

Comment: @Dan Bron: thanks for your comments, they definitely make me feel better about my writing style.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Avon. It seems the little *Green Eggs and Ham* exchange between Dan and I confused you. I'm saying this: leading with *As* introduces weakness, but deleting *that* focuses power. But in the other hand--from a strictly stylistic perspective--if the expression is being used over and over again, there may be times when the strength of the expression can yield for the sake of variety.

Comment: @ScotM not at all. I was referring to the OP's post only (I agree that it sounds weak as well). "As the main point, our prices are the best." sounds like nonsense to me. I can't make sense of it. I don't think I have ever come across that construct ("As the main point,") and rearranging the independent clauses into their natural position (so there is no comma) only reinforces that opinion. Maybe I should ask about it in another question (in ELL perhaps). Edit: Probably an AmE thing.

Comment: Perhaps all your reviewer wanted was sentence variety. As you said you may have overused the form "The main point is." Try this: if I keep saying *this is the heart of what I'm saying*, that could mean I have a better way of writing what I just wrote. Hey, in a natural conversation, I do that - but in writing, standards are higher. So I'd spell out my main point without saying here is the main point.

Answer (score 6):

*"The main point is that ..."*, *"The problem is that ..."* are perfectly fine. The alternatives you mentioned are inferior, if not incorrect. The Corpus of Contemporary American English returns **2391** results for *"the problem is that"*, while it only gives **124** results for *"as the problem"*, none of which are used in the style that you (or to be exact, the reviewer) suggested.

Reference:

[**Corpus of Contemporary American English**](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)

Comment: I agree with this answer, and I'd add that simply removing "that" also makes the sentence worse rather than better. Keep your original wording; reviewers are not infallible.

Comment: "Amercian" -- two of the same typos in this answer

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Masoud-Ata that your constructions are fine.

Some times (many times?) the word "that" can be left out of a sentence with no harm.  Sometimes, "that" is unnecessary and leaving it out can actually make a sentence cleaner.  If you have strict word counts for a paper, eliminating "that"s can help stay within limits. And sometimes "that" *is* overused and causes the writing to sound repetitive.

But just because "that" is *often optional* does not mean that it is *always prohibited*.  Some people are given the advice of avoiding "that" in school, and they take it as a hard-and-fast rule rather than the stylistic advice that it really is.  I suspect your reviewer may be one of these overly-concrete people who demand that if "that" *could* be taken out, then it *must* be taken out.  (I've worked with one or two myself!)